# Scope variables undefined when testing controller with Karma and Jasmine with ng-scenario as framework

Tags: angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-scenario

I've just started to discover angular unit testing mysteries using `Karma` & `Jasmine` and I have some problems with `controllers` tests. I've wrote tests to see if variables are defined: `expect(scope.someVariable).toBeDefined()`. Everything worked as expected ( every test was successfully ) untill I've added `ng-scenario` in `karma.conf.js` file.

I'm using `node` to run tests.

**Problem:** After adding `ng-scenario` in karma configuration file as framework all tests for checking if scope variables are defined are failing. Before adding `ng-scenario` all tests were successfully. ***Do you have any ideea why is this happening ?***

**Karma Conf file:**

> ```
> module.exports = function(config) {
> config.set({
> basePath: '',
> frameworks: ['ng-scenario','jasmine'],
> files: [    'app/plugins/jquery/jquery.js',
>   'app/plugins/angular/angular.js',     'app/plugins/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js',
>   'app/plugins/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
>   'app/plugins/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
>   'app/plugins/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
>   'app/plugins/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
>   'app/plugins/angular-route/angular-route.js',     'app/plugins/angular-utf8-base64/angular-utf8-base64.js',
>   'app/scripts/*.js',
>   'app/scripts/**/*.js',
>   'test/**/*.js',
>
>     'app/views/templates/*.html'
> ],
>
> preprocessors : { 'app/views/templates/*.html': 'html2js'     },
> exclude: ['app/plugins/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js'],
> port: 8080,
> logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
> autoWatch: false,
> browsers: ['Chrome'],
> singleRun: false   }); };
> ```

**Controller test:**

> ```
> 'use strict'
>
> describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {
>
>  
>   beforeEach(module('qunizGameApp'));
>   
>   var MainCtrl,scope, configService,feedbackService,authService,notify,resourceService;
>
>
>   beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope,_configService_,_feedbackService_, _authService_,_notify_, _resourceService_) {
>
>      scope = $rootScope.$new();
>      MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
>        $scope: scope,
>        configService:_configService_,
>        feedbackService:_feedbackService_,
>        authService:_authService_,
>        notify:_notify_,
>        resourceService:_resourceService_
>  
>      });
>      configService=_configService_;
>        feedbackService=_feedbackService_;
>        authService=_authService_;
>        notify=_notify_;
>        resourceService=_resourceService_;   }));
>  
>    it('should be defined -configService', function () {   
>       expect(scope.configService).toBeDefined();  
>    });   
>    it('should be defined - resourceService', function () {   
>       expect(scope.resourceService).toBeDefined();   
>    });  
>    it('should be defined - sidebarVisible', function () {   
>       expect(scope.sidebarVisible).toBeDefined();   }); 
>    });
> ```

**Proof of working test before including `ng-scenario`:**

[image: karma is working without ng-scenario framework]

**Proof of failure test after including `ng-scenario`:**

[image: karma is failing with ng-scenario framework]

And a wierd thing is that if I debug the test in my `chrome` console, variables are defined:

[image: debugging tests]

**Things read on interned and tried:**

1.I've tried to define variables on scope in `beforeEach` section as a mock data.

2.I've tried to inject all other controller dependencies ( with undescored name as paramaters)

You can see 1 and 2 below

> ```
> beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope,_configService_,_feedbackService_, _authService_,_notify_, _resourceService_) {
>
>     scope = $rootScope.$new();
>     scope.configService=_configService_;
>     scope.authService=_authService_;
>     scope.resourceService=_resourceService_;
>     scope.sidebarVisible={};
>     MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
>       $scope: scope,
>         configService:_configService_,
>         feedbackService:_feedbackService_,
>         authService:_authService_,
>         notify:_notify_,
>         resourceService:_resourceService_
>     
>     });
>     configService=_configService_;
>     feedbackService=_feedbackService_;
>     authService=_authService_;
>     notify=_notify_;
>     resourceService=_resourceService_;   }));
> ```

But `scope.configService`, `scope.resourceService` and `scope.sidebarVisible` are still undefined at the moment of test

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with ng-scenario when using it with Karma. The moment I included it in karma.conf.js file, none of my tests was passing. Just don't use ng-scenario - use Protractor for integration testing. https://github.com/angular/protractor